# Automatically update data on website database triggered by date and time

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, scheduled-tasks

I have a condition that I have to update data automatically on my website, which is triggered by time that I've set before.

EXAMPLE :

> i've set the update for 29-05-2018 20.20 then the website will do update in that date and that time without any trigger, and no need to
>   open the website.

Comment: you can use cron for the scheduled updates

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/zzqUJMEEZjc... if the data is in spreadsheet  format

Answer (score 0):

Create a Controller name Cron.php
than make a function run_every_day()
now put all your condition in this function than go to your cpanel search for a cron tab. Click on it create a cron task
give it the url root/index.php/cron/run_every_day
in the cron seeting set the time 1 day so it will run each day on specific time you set.

Hope this helps

Comment: how this work on localhost, like xampp, can that method still work? or i need support app to do that on my localhost?